# Is there a way to figure out which file is stored at a particular block?

Tags: fsck-hfs

I've just checked my SSD with `sudo fsck_hfs -fy -S /dev/disk2s2` and it threw some errors, for example:

`block 2760096: *** NO MATCH ***`

What I would like to know which file is located at offset 2760096.